# How to read from a session ID when knowing the session ID from a GET request

Tags: php, session

This must be so simple, but I am just not getting forward.

I initiate a session and use the normal PHP Session handler using a cookie.

I now have a upload form which is using a Flash uploader. Unfortunately the Flash uploader is not reading the cookie from the session and opening a new session as the Flash is running in its own instance.

So I have written a workaround which is passing me the session variable in a GET parameter.

Reading the session ID from the get parameter works perfectly.

```
$SID = $_GET['session'];

session_start();
session_id($SID);

$dataFromSession = $_SESSION['data'];
```

Unfortunately `$dataFromSession / $_SESSION['data']` seems to be empty.

This must be the most simple thing ever...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

> If id is specified, it will replace
>   the current session id. session_id()
>   needs to be called before
>   session_start() for that purpose.

You call `session_id()` after `session_start()`. That could be the problem for example?